# how do i show path in polyline with multiple coordinates in flutter with google maps

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter, dart

I have an app in which i need to record a walk taken by a user. now when the user starts the walk i want to keep trace if its location and then at the end of the walk i will show the complete path that user traveled now google maps shows the path as the shortest path it can find between two points. but what if the user wanders wherever he wants??? how do i draw poly line with multiple coordinate points?

I know how to create poly line with two coordinates but can i not add more coordinates?